# What does a isStable really mean in angular?

Tags: angular

In angular, we can get the reference of the application running using the **ApplicationRef** Service, which we can then inject for further use. In there, I found a property **isStable** whose definition looks quite simple but I really want to understand how Angular considers one application to be stable?

**Definition:**

> `isStable: Observable<boolean>` : Read-Only Returns an Observable that
> indicates when the application is stable or unstable.

Do they check the main stack to be empty and the event queue to be empty for calling it stable or something else? Also, reference of the angular app means the process running in the browser, right ?

Comment: have you looked at the [official documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationRef#is-stable-examples) that provide usage & explanations?

Comment: Yes, I asked the question after checking the official docs. There was nothing about what angular considers to be a stable application. Just the fact that if a recurrent async task starts when the app starts, then the isStable Observable wil never emit true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ApplicationRef.isStable` source code is available on GitHub as part of the [Angular repository](https://github.com/angular/angular).

**[application_ref.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b6cd38ff055f003f92fff4c3e27d165fb4437057/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts#L645)**

```js
const isStable = new Observable<boolean>((observer: Observer<boolean>) => {
    // Create the subscription to onStable outside the Angular Zone so that
    // the callback is run outside the Angular Zone.
    let stableSub: Subscription;
    this._zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        stableSub = this._zone.onStable.subscribe(() => {
        NgZone.assertNotInAngularZone();

        // Check whether there are no pending macro/micro tasks in the next tick
        // to allow for NgZone to update the state.
        scheduleMicroTask(() => {
            if (!this._stable && !this._zone.hasPendingMacrotasks &&
                !this._zone.hasPendingMicrotasks) {
            
                this._stable = true;
                observer.next(true);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

So an application is considered stable when its dependency-injected zone has no current or scheduled micro or macro tasks.

**[ng_zone.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b6cd38ff055f003f92fff4c3e27d165fb4437057/packages/core/src/zone/ng_zone.ts#L401)**

```js
onHasTask:
    (delegate: ZoneDelegate, current: Zone, target: Zone, hasTaskState: HasTaskState) => {
      delegate.hasTask(target, hasTaskState);
      if (current === target) {
        // We are only interested in hasTask events which originate from our zone
        // (A child hasTask event is not interesting to us)
        if (hasTaskState.change == 'microTask') {
          zone._hasPendingMicrotasks = hasTaskState.microTask;
          updateMicroTaskStatus(zone);
          checkStable(zone);
        } else if (hasTaskState.change == 'macroTask') {
          zone.hasPendingMacrotasks = hasTaskState.macroTask;
        }
      }
    },
```